# Certificate Error due to broken https in Google Chromium on Ubuntu 14

Tags: google-chrome, ubuntu, https

When I access the specific https web sites by Google Chromium (Chrome) web browser on Ubuntu 14.04, and failed to read css file. So, Chromium shows only html page.

Here is the parts of actual error message by insect amazon.co.jp.

```
Certificate Error
There are issues with the site's certificate chain (net::ERR_CERTIFICATE_TRANSPARENCY_REQUIRED).

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_INSECURE_RESPONSE
https://images-fe.ssl-images-amazon.com/images/I/71pSmmb%2BprL._RC%7C01e2ha…OL.css,013I2i6KemL.css,21boYNdV4IL.css_.css#AUIClients/NavDesktopMetaAsset
```

These kind of error happened other https web sites (not every https web sites). The different web browsers don't show error. And this error has been happened since few weeks ago.

I have tried reset and clear History, Cache, Setting in Chromium, but nothing changed.

Comment: I found the solution in https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/chromium-browser/+bug/1641380
This is the bug of Chromium, update fix the bug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Updating to Chromium to version 54 resolves the issue](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=665484)